# Not able to see List in window initially

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I want to display list items in a separate window. But when the window opens it doesn't display the list. I can click the list item but I cannot see it. If I click on data it appears one by one.Also, when I scroll down the list it displays the data.

I have tired using

```
m_bList_index.UpdateData(FALSE); 
m_bList_index.UpdateWindow();
m_bList.UpdateData(FALSE);
m_bList.UpdateWindow();
```

at  the last of the DisplayList() function, but that didn't resolve the issue. Below is the code which I want to edit.

```
    CListBox m_bList_index; 
    CMyListBox m_bList; 
    BOOL CBatch::OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();
        m_status.Empty();
        m_bIndex.Empty();
        m_elapsed_time.Empty();
        m_estimated_time.Empty();
        CenterWindow();
        m_bList.CreateColumn();
        DisplayList();
        return TRUE;
        // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
    }

    void CBatch::DisplayList()
    {
        unsigned int size;  
        m_bList_title.ResetContent(); 
        m_bList_title.SetHorizontalExtent(2000);
        m_bList_title.InsertString(0, theApp.m_pFieldBTitleStr);
        theApp.bCheckList->SetSortingType(theApp.checkList->GetSortingType());
        theApp.bCheckList->Sort();
        size = theApp.bCheckList->GetSize();            
        m_bList_index.SetRedraw(FALSE);   
        m_bList_index.ResetContent();
        m_bList_index.SetHorizontalExtent(2000);
        m_bList.SetRedraw(FALSE);   
        m_bList.DeleteAllItems();
        m_bList.SetHorizontalExtent(2000);

char ColumnName[256];
char strColumnValue[256];
double fColumnValue;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{      
    char buffer[255];
    int index = 0;

    if(m_bList.m_SerialNo)
    {
        sprintf(buffer,"%d",i+1);
        m_bList.InsertItem(i, buffer,0);
        index = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        theApp.bCheckList->m_checkArray[i]->get((CV_CHECK_FIELD)(m_bList.ListColumns[0]),buffer);
        m_bList.InsertItem(i, buffer,0);
        index = 1;
    }
    for(; index < m_bList.NoofColumns; index++)
    {

        LV_COLUMN rightjust;
        rightjust.mask = LVCF_FMT;
        rightjust.fmt = LVCFMT_RIGHT;
        m_bList.SetColumn(index+m_bList.m_SerialNo,&rightjust);

        memset(buffer,0x0,256);
        theApp.bCheckList->m_checkArray[i]->get((CV_CHECK_FIELD)(m_bList.ListColumns[index]),buffer);

        if ( (m_bList.ListColumns[index] ==  CV_CHECK_FIELD_FILELOCATION) ||
            (m_bList.ListColumns[index] ==  CV_CHECK_FIELD_POSTED_DATE) ||
            (m_bList.ListColumns[index] == CV_CHECK_FIELD_STATUS))
            strcpy(buffer, buffer);
        }

        m_bList.SetItemText(i,index+m_bList.m_SerialNo,buffer); 

    }

}
        m_bList.SetSel(0, TRUE);
        m_bList.SetRedraw(TRUE);
        m_bList_index.SetRedraw(TRUE);
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That's a picture of `CListCtrl` not `CListBox`. Try `m_ListCtrl->Invalidate(TRUE)`

Comment: I tried using invalidate at the end but issue remains same.

Comment: You don't need to use Invalidate, and you don't need to use SetRedraw. You're doing the calls from OnInitdialog. During OnInitDialog, the dialog is invisible and won't be drawing controls. At the point the dialog will be displayed, then the dialog will be drawn. All the names are rather confusing... if a variable starts with m_b, that means it is a member variable that is a BOOL (Win32) or bool (C++). You're clearing out all the data in the controls and at the end you call UpdateData(FALSE), but we have no idea what that might be doing because you're not showing it.

Comment: `OnInitDIalog` looks more or less correct, there is something you're not telling us. What happens if you move the CBatch dialog off screen and back with the mouse? Is it drawn correctly after doing so? Also show us what are: `m_bList_title`, `// Doing some stuff here...`. Try to simply your code, add just some lines of hardcoded data to the list without calling anything else and see if that changes something.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks. I have added more code what I am doing inside the code.  CListBox  m_bList_title. Its the object of CListBox. On the other side. I have complied this code in Visual Studio 2012. Should I try in Visual Studio 2019. Could this be due to older version of VS?. This is reproducible once in 20 tries, and seen more frequently in Windows 7 as compared to Windows 10.